# puppet get node ip and use it

Tags: ip, puppet

My node's have several ip address. And i need to use only 192.168.*.* in my templates.
Example: server has ip 192.168.156.68 and 10.248.41.70.
In my manifest i write something like:

```
if $::ipaddress =~ /^192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/ {
  notice("ok")
}
else {
  warning("don't know what to do with IP address $::ipaddress")
}
```

and in templates:
`ListenAddress <%= @ipaddress %>`

In result, on the nodes conf file i get:
`ListenAddress 10.248.41.70`

but i have to get
`ListenAddress 192.168.156.68`

Can anybody can explain me how to do it ?

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the ip address before placing it in the conf file? It is unclear what you are asking. Also, what version of Puppet?

Comment: Matt, i apologize for a long answer. I try to get remote ip address by regexp, and then use it in my .erb template file . `puppetserver version: 2.7.2
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use temp variable: validIp

```
   if $::ipaddress =~ /^192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/ {
      notice("ok")
      $validIp= $::ipaddress
    }
    else {
      warning("don't know what to do with IP address $::ipaddress")
      $validIp= 'undefined'
    }
```

And in template:

```
ListenAddress <%= @validIp %>
```

Or you can check ip in template.

Comment: i apologize for a long answer, but in this way i get `ListenAddress undefined`